# Align words in cells of a table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Consider a table like this:

```
| text1      | text2        |
|------------|--------------|
| a b c      | AAA BBB CCC  | 
|------------|--------------|        
|            |   aa bb cc   |
|------------|--------------|        
| AA BB CC   |              |
```

Now I want that a is aligned with AA, b with BB, c with CC and AAA with aa and so on.

Is it possible to do this in LaTeX (if possible with a simple and elegant syntax)?

I should add, that for my purpose the three tokens are generated by a command `\foo` for example instead of writing a b c directly into the table there is something like `\foo{a'}{b'}{c'}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `tabular` environment along with `multcol` package.  I defined the `\foo` macro as requested that takes three parameters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{l@{\hspace{1mm}}}% Adjust horizontal spacing between columns here
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{m{#1}}% Centered columns of fixed width
\newcommand{\foo}[3]{#1&#2&#3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|LLL|LLL|}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{text1} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{text2} \\ \hline
 a &b&c      & AAA & BBB & CCC   \\
\hline
   & &       &   aa & bb & cc   \\
\hline
AA &BB &CC & & & \\
\hline  
\end{tabular}     

Using the foo macro: 
\begin{tabular}{|LLL|LLL|}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{text1} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{text2} \\ \hline
 \foo{a}{b}{c}      & \foo{AAA}{BBB}{CCC}   \\
\hline
 \foo{}{}{}&    \foo{aa}{bb}{cc}\\
\hline
\foo{AA}{BB}{CC}&  \foo{}{}{} \\
\hline  
\end{tabular}     

With fixed width columns:
\newcommand{\Size}{1.0cm}%
\begin{tabular}{|C{\Size}C{\Size}C{\Size}|C{\Size}C{\Size}C{\Size}|}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{text1} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{text2} \\ \hline
 \foo{a}{b}{c}      & \foo{AAA}{BBB}{CCC}   \\
\hline
 \foo{}{}{}&    \foo{aa}{bb}{cc}\\
\hline
\foo{AA}{BB}{CC}&  \foo{}{}{} \\
\hline  
\end{tabular}                   
\end{document}
```

If you want more spacing between columns you can adjust the `newcolumntype`, or just use `l` instead of `L` for the columns specifications.

You can adjust the width of the columns by changing the parameter passed in to the `C` column type.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to adjust this such that each \foo{x}{y}{z} is centered?

Comment: Sure, replace the `l` (left alignment) with `c` (center alignment) in the column specification.

Comment: Is it possible to have all "big" columns with the same fixed width?

Comment: Updated to include fixed width columns.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\rlap` (and `\llap` and `\clap`) to overwrite certain components in text. Additionally, `\phantom` can be use to typeset something without actually doing it. The example below can be modified to have a modify the overlap. Regardless, this does not require any additional packages to be included.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l|l}\hline
  text1 & text2 \\ \hline
  \rlap{a}\phantom{AA}\ \rlap{b}\phantom{BB}\ \rlap{c}\phantom{CC} & AAA\ BBB\  CCC \\ \hline
  & \rlap{aa}\phantom{AAA}\ \rlap{bb}\phantom{BBB}\ \rlap{cc}\phantom{CCC} \\ \hline
  AA\ BB\ CC \\ \hline  
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Table with alignment]